# createrepo fails with os.getcwd

Tags: yum, puppet

i'm starting to use puppet.
i wanted to have my own yum repository to serve puppet server so i issued

```
 yum install createrepo
```

no errors reported (cenotos 5.5) after that i issued

```
createrepo /var/www/html/repository
```

but i get:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/createrepo/genpkgmetadata.py", line 724, in ?
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/share/createrepo/genpkgmetadata.py", line 592, in main
    cmds, directories = parseArgs(args)
  File "/usr/share/createrepo/genpkgmetadata.py", line 431, in parseArgs
    cmds['basedir'] = os.getcwd()
 OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

note the folder:

```
/var/www/html
```

exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem
os.getcwd() throws exception because as it turned the directory i was in was deleted by another process.  all i needed to do was to change to a valid directory.  interesting watson.